# Generate ID for a column in place of null using last ID present in that column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a table structure like this and wanted to generate the keys for the remaining category without mutating already present keys, where null is present in continuation to values present in the category_key column using the last key present for that in category_key (max of category_key).

[image]

Adding as a text for ease:
category    categroy_key
category a  1
category z  null
category b  2
category c  3
category y  null
category d  4
category e  5
category g  6
category h  7
category i  8
category j  9
category k  10
category l  11
category m  12
category f  null

order can be anything for the generated keys for the null ones, they just need to be unique from the earlier ones.

e.g.

[image]

Tried to use monotonically_increasing_id() as well, but didn't work out as it replaces all the keys and generates them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example will give you a complete `categroy_key` column without null values, where numbering of previous null elements starts from max value in `categroy_key` + 1

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
# The data that you supplied
data = [("category a", 1), ("category z", None), ("category b", 2), ("category c", 3), ("category y", None), ("category d", 4), ("category e", 5), ("category g", 6), ("category h", 7), ("category i", 8), ("category j", 9), ("category k", 10), ("category l", 11), ("category m", 12), ("category f", None)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["category", "categroy_key"])
df.show()

# The maximum key we should continue from
max_key = df.agg(F.max(F.col("categroy_key")).alias("max")).collect()[0]["max"]

# Construct a column containing a new key value for all rows with null in col categroy_key. The key value starts from max_key + 1
df_continued_key = df.withColumn("continued_key", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("categroy_key")).orderBy(F.lit(1))) + max_key)
# For each row, duplicate the continued_key column value in categroy_key column if the categroy_key column is null
df_with_complete_categroy_key_column =  df_continued_key.withColumn("categroy_key", F.coalesce("categroy_key", "continued_key")).drop("continued_key")
df_with_complete_categroy_key_column.show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------+
|  category|categroy_key|
+----------+------------+
|category a|           1|
|category z|        null|
|category b|           2|
|category c|           3|
|category y|        null|
|category d|           4|
|category e|           5|
|category g|           6|
|category h|           7|
|category i|           8|
|category j|           9|
|category k|          10|
|category l|          11|
|category m|          12|
|category f|        null|
+----------+------------+

+----------+------------+
|  category|categroy_key|
+----------+------------+
|category z|          13|
|category y|          14|
|category f|          15|
|category a|           1|
|category b|           2|
|category c|           3|
|category d|           4|
|category e|           5|
|category g|           6|
|category h|           7|
|category i|           8|
|category j|           9|
|category k|          10|
|category l|          11|
|category m|          12|
+----------+------------+
```